# How to get all direct(immediate) rows from WebElement Table

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

From the below table I need immediate row elements using Xpath or "css-selector" or Selenium API :- element.findelements. Please help.

```
<table id ="Main">
<tbody>
<tr id="row_1">
<tr id="row_1_1">
<tr id="row_1_1_1">
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr id="row_2">
</tr>
<tr id="row_3">
<tr id="row_3_1">
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Expected Output:-

```
[<tr id="row_1">,<tr id="row_2">,<tr id="row_3">]
```

Imp Note:- I am looking for a generic solution. Sometimes tbody wont be present in the table. I am having Table WebElement with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath union operator (`|`) to combine multiple xpath expressions, f.e one to handle the case when `tbody` exists, and another for the case when `tbody` doesn't exist :

```
//table[@id='Main']/tbody/tr | //table[@id='Main']/tr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below locator

```
By.cssSelector("table#Main > tbody > tr")

Or

By.xpath("//table[@id='Main']/tbody/tr")


List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table#Main > tbody > tr"));
for(WebElement ele : allRows) {
    //do your operation with that row
    //ele.getText();
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning the generic use case requirement.

Comment: I have used that before itself, but not fulfilling my requirement :(

Comment: update your proper requirements in question. Will try to give solution.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp here is all you need, try the above one without the tbody part and include a part where there is no tr tag as parent